Upgrading My Yuba Mundo V4 from SRAM X3 3x7 to Shimano CUES 2x11
I'm looking into getting better gearing for the Yuba Mundo V4 that I just got since even though the drive train works fine and doesn't have any issues, it's got less than adequate low gears, so to fix the issue I'm looking to get a super high range 11-45 rear and 22/36 front drivetrain setup running since that's within specifications for Shimano CUES, has anyone else tried this and are there any obstacles or things to know regarding doing the conversion? here's the parts list I have so far below. I tried doing my research based on what Shimano recommends.

2 CN LG-500 chains (needs the extra chain length since it's a longtail cargo bike)
Origin 8 MT-2100 48H rear hub
CS-LG400-11 (11-45) rear cassette
RD-U6020-11 rear derailleur
SL-U6000-11R rear shifter
FC-U4000-2 175mm (22-36) crankset
FD-U6000-M front derailleur
SL-U6000-L front shifter


I have no experience with this bike or CUES components, so not an answer. What I found online hints that the bike currently has a 14-28 freewheel. Maybe changing that to a "megarange" with 14-34 (and perhaps a longer chain) could already help you? It's not the same gearing as your proposed 22x45 though. But it would only be ~20 bucks to try instead of replacing half the bike.

Seems totally in line with the specs (but no personal experience, so not an answer). My only question marks are about the crankset, but it's because I'm not familiar with this kind of bottom brackets, and the rear hub, because I don't know the original specs of the bike. You will probably need to order new spokes and nipples if the lengths don't match (if you can find such wheel assembled, it check the prices, a new wheel may be cheaper than rebuilding from your rim).

22/45 is at the extreme end of low gearing and might be overkill. My trail bike has 22/36 which yields about 5kph at a regular spin speed on 8-10% grade. Im wondering if that combo can be useful without stalling the bike.
